# Google Identity-Aware-Proxy and Firewall Rules for Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, google-iap

I want to configure Google Identity Aware Proxy for an application running on Google Kubernetes Engine. To do that i added an Ingress to my Kubernetes Configuration so i get a Load-Balancer to configure as an identity-aware-proxy.

Now GCP shows me a few warnings that are about problematic firewall rules. As all of these rules were configured by GKE i'm not quite sure if they are a problem.

[image: FirewallRules]

As far as i understand it `10.128.0.0/9` is the default VPC for projects and `10.56.0.0/14` is the ip range for all containers in my kubernetes cluster.

To me this means that "only" internal traffic inside my project/kubernetes-cluster can bypass the IAP. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re correct. However, keep in mind that if you have set up an internal load balancer the traffic will bypass the IAP.

Answer (score 2):

Note, you can natively integrate with IAP through Ingress
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-kubernetes-howto